# How to handle a Custom exception with @ErrorHandler for HttpClientErrorException?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am working in a Spring Boot project and I m making a couple of HTTP calls to another **apis**.
Using Rest-Template to make those calls and using @ControlAdvice and @ExceptionHandler to handle the exceptions.
I have a conceptual doubt and I would like to verify if I am doing Ok or there's another solution.
I will use example code, so to make things more clear.

Suppose I have Service A ,making a HTTL CALL to **"Api-1"**

```
 public String fetchApi1() {
    return  restTemplateHelper.postForEntity(String.class, "http://api-1/users");
 }
```

And I have Service B ,making a HTTL CALL to **"Api-2"**

```
 public String fetchApi2() {
    return  restTemplateHelper.postForEntity(String.class, "http://api-2/users");
 }
```

I am catching HttpClientErrorException in my Error handler this way:()

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException .class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHTTPClientError(HttpClientErrorException ex, WebRequest request){
    return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

The buildErrorResponse() method, will generate and return a generic error response to the client.
That s great!

But, suppose that I need to call a new Api,API3.
API3 when returns a 409 code Error it returns addition data in the body ,so the global Error Handler it s not useful for me ,because I need to check additional things for **THAT SPECIFIC API CALL and THAT Specific ERROR CODE.**

So, this is what I did:

```
    public String fetchApi3() {
       try {
            return  restTemplateHelper.postForEntity(String.class, "http://api-3/users");
       }  catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            if (checkError(e)==HttpStatus.CONFLICT){
              throw new MyCustom409Exeption(e);
            }
            throw e;
       }
    }
```

As you can see , Service C is making a HTTL CALL to "Api3".

There I am catching the HttpClientErrorException inside the service ,ask if the status code is 409 ,if the status code is 409 I  create  a custom exception (MyCustom409Exeption).
MyCustom409Exeption will know what data to extract from original exception.(For example, the body)

Then of course I throw that exception, and if the HttpClientErrorException exception is not 409 I throw the original exception.
Finally I add in my Global exception handler an entry to manage that custom exception.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustom409Exeption.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHTTPClientError(HttpClientErrorException ex, WebRequest request){
    return buildSpecific409ErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

The buildSpecific409ErrorResponse() method, will generate and return a similar response than always, but it will add some extra data (In fact, the Response entity I use, it s the same )

So ,is ok my approach?
Each time I need an specific treatment for errors, when calling an external API I need to catch the Exceptions properly.
(Let me know if something it s not clear please)

Answer (score 0):

If you have similar exception response logic in different REST clients, I think you should place logic in one place not smear it in different places and not rethrow new exception for any new status code.
Something like this:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException .class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHTTPClientError(HttpClientErrorException ex, WebRequest request){
        if (ex.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST){
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    } else if {
      //another logic
    } else {
      //default 500 response
    }
    }
```

And if you have too many handled status codes you can use pattern Strategy instead if or switch case.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks ! Yes of course if I have similar logic, the idea it s to put it in just one place. (For example all 409 Error will be handled in the same place) However in my example I have an Api (Api 3) that will respond 409 Code but it will have special data in its body, so I cant handle it in the same place where I am handling all 409 Status code. That s why I created a custom Exception and I had to catch the HttpClientErrorException  in the service itself and then do a simple check to see if the custom Exception needs to be throwed